# Using regex in PSQL Case Statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Working on a rails app with postgresql.

I am trying to implement a pg constraint using a case statement.

```
          ALTER TABLE geolocation_postcodes
        ADD CONSTRAINT canadian_format CHECK (
          CASE WHEN country_code = 'CA' AND code !~ '\A^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d\Z' THEN FALSE
          END
          );
```

When trying to insert an instance (which should pass) it is stopped by the constraint every time:

Input:

```
Geolocation::Postcode.insert(code: "G6V 4C9", country_code: "CA", created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
```

Result:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  new row for relation "geolocation_postcodes" violates check constraint "canadian_format" DETAIL:  Failing row contains (46, G6V 4C9, t, 2021-04-07 01:37:34.005891, 2021-04-07 01:37:34.005896, CA).
```

Comment: What is the filtering logic that you actually want to have on country codes?

Comment: Postcodes will be from different countries which have different formats hence different constraints.  So if the country is Canada (value of “CA” for country code), the format is checked against the canadian_format constraint. 

So basically,  if the country_code is “CA”, the code (IE. G5V 4C9) is checked to see if it matches the regex expression.  If it fails, the record bounces.

Comment: I have given an answer below.  Basically, your check constraint should be spelling out what the positive accepted cases are.  You don't even need a `CASE` expression here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The logic inside the check constraint should be for the *positive* match cases.  So I would use here:

```sql
ALTER TABLE geolocation_postcodes
ADD CONSTRAINT canadian_format CHECK (
    (country_code = 'CA' AND code ~ '\A[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]\s[0-9][A-Z][0-9]\Z') OR
    -- other possible matching country codes here
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. Your regex doesn't do what you think it does.
2. You only cover Canadian postal codes (but this is probably intentional).
3. I suspect that your CHECK constraint didn't get to the database properly.

**(1)** Your regex is attempting to use both `\A` (beginning of string) and `^` (beginning of line). You only want one of those and I'd go with `\A` for consistency with `\Z` and `\A` in Ruby:

```
\A[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d\Z
```

**(2)** You can fix this by renaming the constraint to something like `postal_code_format` and restructuring the logic like:

```
code ~ case country_code
       when 'CA' then '\A[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d\Z'
       when 'US' then ...
       end
```

That structure makes the SQL `case` look like a Ruby hash and keeps everything together and easy to read.

**(3)** This one is probably at the root of your problems. I'm guessing that you have something like this in a migration:

```
connection.execute(%Q(
  ALTER TABLE geolocation_postcodes
  ADD CONSTRAINT canadian_format CHECK (
    CASE WHEN country_code = 'CA' AND code !~ '\A^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d\Z' THEN FALSE
    END
  );
))
```

or a heredoc or other double quoted string. All those strings will interpret backslashes so `\A` will end up as `A`, `\d` as `d`, ... and by the time your regex gets to the database it will look like:

```
A^[A-Z]d[A-Z] d[A-Z]dZ
```

and your CHECK will fail.

If you use a single quoted string and the right regex, things should be okay:

```
connection.execute(%q(
  alter table geolocation_postcodes
  add constraint postal_code_format check (
    code ~ case country_code
           when 'CA' then '\A[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d\Z'
           end
  )
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.  Very clear answer.  I was able to solve my issue, improve my code and learn. I was wondering why the \d wasn't working for digits...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What does this have to with Oracle?

Comment: So... I've been conducting a bunch of tests using psql regex in rails migrations.  I am not able to escape the letters properly, hence \d show up as d in the database.  I tried single and double quotes.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The `%q(...)` version in my answer should work. `%q(...)` works like a single-quoted string in Ruby but lets you include single quotes without escaping them.

Comment: I might have to stick to [0-9] instead of \d

Comment: Again, thanks both of you for your answers.